Add labels to boxplot
I'm trying to recreate a screenshot with some boxplots in excel. Specifically, I would like to add labels for the interquartile range, median, 10th-90th percentile, and current value. What I'm looking for is something like this:
However, when I try to incorporate this in excel I can only manage to get the following: 
How should I add these labels and how can I add the current value in the graph?
